# Footer Image not showing on IE8,9,10 but is on all other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a footer image that is not showing on IE8, 9 and 10 but is on other browsers, and despite searching for an answer can't work out why.

I am new at this so there may be glaring errors in my code, but would be incredibly grateful if someone could provide an answer.

The code is:

```css
.ffooterimage {
        position:relative;
        height:325px;
        max-width:100%;
     
 }
    .fabsolute {
        width:150px;
        height:200px;
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-550px;
     
} 

    #fposition {
        width:500px;
        height:0px;
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-70px;
     top: -110px;
     bottom: 0px;
     font-size: 13px;
   }
     
    #flonglinks {
        position: relative;
        width:600px;
        height:0px;
        display:block;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-70px;
     top: -25px;
     font-family: "UbuntuRegular",Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
     font-size: 11px;
    }

#linksleft {
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
    height:0px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-620px;
 top: -100px;
 font-family: "UbuntuRegular",Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
}

ul li {
list-style-type: none; 
}
```

```html
<!-- FOOTER BEGINS -->
    <div class="ffooterimage">

          <div class="fabsolute"><img src="/images/website-footer.jpg" alt="" height="px"/></div></div>
       <div id="fposition">
          Company info here
       </div>
       <div id="flonglinks"><p><a href="/Home/Privacy"style="color:black;" >Privacy </a>| <a href="/Home/Disclaimer"style="color:black;">Disclaimer</a> |<a href="/Home/Contact"style="color:black;"> Contact us</a> | <a href="Complaints-Procedures.pdf" style="color:black;">Complaints </a> | <a href="/logbook-loans-london"style="color:black;">London</a> | <a href="/logbook-loans-manchester"style="color:black;">Manchester</a> | <a href="/logbook-loans-sheffield"style="color:black;">Sheffield</a> | <a href="/logbook-loans-liverpool"style="color:black;">Liverpool</a></p>
       <div id="linksleft">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com" style="color:black;">Example</a>
      <li><a href="http://www.example.com" style="color:black;">Example link</a>
      <li><a href="http://www.example.com" style="color:black;">Example link</a>
      <li><a href="http://www.example.com" style="color:black;">Example link</a>
      <li><a href="http://www.example.com" style="color:black;">Example link</a>
       </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

     <!-- FOOTER ENDS -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove `height="px"` in img tag